# How to run around 15 docker containers with amazon ecs

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

My dockerized application has 12 services in docker-compose.yml, now I want to deploy this application on AWS ECS so any idea how to do that?

In task definition, we can add only up to 10 containers, also is there a way to add multiple task definitions in services?

Answer (score 2):

You should not put all the service in a single task definition, better to run each task in a separate service and for service to service communications use [service discovery](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ecs-service-discovery/) or [internal load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-load-balancing.html).

> In task definition, we can add only up to 10 containers, also is there a way to add multiple task definitions in services

Beside 10 containers limit, there are many other issues with this approach

- You **can not scale one container**, for example scaling PHP container will scale Nginx as well
- Hard to maintain replica and essential container for the service
- Not a production grade approach as it uses linking for service to service communication
- Fewer resources utilization

Or if you need a quick fix then break the task definition into a dependency group, **create two task definition for depended containers so they will able to communicate with each** other being part of the same task definition.